# How to get the different size of multiple specified directories in unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command, sudo

I want to get the size of each specified directory after running some commands.
For example, I want to clean all the cache in `/var` using

```
/var : sudo yum clean all
```

Then, get the size of the following directories:

```
/var
/boot
/opt
```

I can write for example the following:

```
sudo du -sh /var
sudo du -sh /boot
sudo du -sh /opt
```

But I want to merge them in one command " sudo du". Is that possible? Then I want to merge it with the "yum clean all" command.

Is there a good practice to do it? I'm new to Unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple directories with du and so do:

```
sudo yum clean all && sudo du -sh /var /boot /opt
```

You run with one sudo operation:

```
sudo sh -c "yum clean all && du -sh /var /boot /opt"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and simple answer!

Comment: `sudo sh -c "yum clean all && du -sh /var /boot /opt"` would do it all with one `sudo` operation.

Comment: Should I add /var before "sudo yum clean all" to specify that I want to clean only this location? (as: "/var: sudo yum clean all && sudo du -sh /var /boot /opt")

Comment: @Mikael Yum clean all will clear the yum package management cache. As this is stored in /var anyway, there is no need to specify the location

Comment: The `/var :` part does not restrict what `sudo yum clean all` does.  It merely confuses things.  If it goes anywhere, @Mikael, it would go as an argument to `yum clean`, possibly instead of `all`, or possibly after `all` — you'd have to study the manual page for `yum` generally, and `yum clean` specifically, to know what makes sense.  However, the prefix does not make sense.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is there a way to show only the free percentage of each directory? instead of all the other info? such as /var 36% /boot 22% /opt 29% ? because right now it's displaying all the info including the used storage and the total size.

Comment: Without going to study the man page, I don't know if there are options to do that.  However, if the worst comes to the worst, you can pipe the output of `df` through `awk` to print only the information you want.

Comment: df --output=pcent /var /boot /opt

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler and Raman. Another sub-question (not sure if I have to post it separately or not though): if I want then to use the Pipe to sort them, let's say "sudo du --output=pcent /var /boot /opt", but I want to sort them per directory (that is, for each directory, sort them according to their pcent), then I can write "| sort -rh" at the end, but I'm not sure if it'll sort them per directory (sort all /var, then all /boot, then all /opt) or I must separate them and have multiple sudo command in this case?

Comment: Post it as another question. You can probably use awk and be more specific about the field you want to sort on.

Comment: I note that I managed to substitute `df` for `du` in my comment, and Raman copied my mistake — sorry to you both.  You'll need a more complex `sort` command — very much more complex.  You get a number followed by a path name, with spaces after the number (and maybe before it?).  You'd like to sort by the first component of the path and then size?  It might be best to run the raw output through a `sed` script or equivalent that converts `#### /path/to/some/where` into `#### /path /path/to/some/where` so you can sort on column 2, then column 1, then column 3, and then filter out column 2.